# Function to loop through partial dependence command in R?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to write a function that will calculate the partial dependence of all the variables in a model and store them in a data frame. But I'm new to loops in R and I'm not sure how to achieve this. Below is some example code to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Setting up the model:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x2 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x3 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x4 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x5 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y <- x1*100 + x2*10
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y)

library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(y~., data=df)
```

Then I'm using the `pdp` package in `R` to calculate the partial dependence (pd). 
What I'm trying to achieve is to write a function that will calc the pd for each variable and then store those values in a data frame. For example, if I were to manually calc the pd for each variable I would do something like this:

```
library(pdp)
pdp  <- partial(rf, pred.var = "x1")
pdp2 <- partial(rf, pred.var = "x2")

:
 etc           
:
pdp5 <- partial(rf, pred.var = "x5")
```

and then create a df of the values and all the y-hats, like so:

```
pdpDF <- data.frame(pdp,pdp2,...,pdp5)
```

But I would like to automate the process. Im not sure how to do this in `R`. Very naively I would say it would look something like this:

```
xVars <- df[-6] # remove y
for (i in 1:length(xVars))
  pdpValues <- partial(rf, pred.var = xVars[I]) #calc pdp for each variable
  pdpVal <-cbind(all the pdpValues for each variable) #column bind all the values
  pdpDF<- data.frame(pdpVal) # Create df
```

but I have no idea how to make this work!? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Consider `sapply` to return a matrix of your partial values which you can later render as data frame:

```
partial_mat <- sapply(names(df[-6]), function(x) partial(rf, pred.var = x))

partial_df <- data.frame(partial_mat)
```

Comment: I was looking into sapply, however when I use it I get the following error: Error in colnames(train)[pred.var] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts. I assume it's because the partial sums return both positive and negative numbers. Does this mean I can't use sapply for my problem?

Comment: Whoops! You are supposed to pass names and not actual column vectors into `partial`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how you want your dataframe, but the following line gives you a list of dataframes for each variable.

```
lapply(1:5, function(i){
  partial(rf, pred.var=paste0("x", i))
})
```

Comment: I ended up following your code with the addition of using  bind_cols() from the dplyr package too make it into a single data frame. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map_dfc` from `purrr`

```
library(pdp)
purrr::map_dfc(names(df)[-1], ~partial(rf, pred.var = .x))

#        x2    yhat      x3 yhat1      x4   yhat2      x5 yhat3       y yhat4
#1  -2.8132  1.7053 -2.8709 12.04 -1.8891  4.9620 -2.6577 10.64 -230.24   7.4
#2  -2.7056  1.7053 -2.7677 12.04 -1.7959  5.3603 -2.5572 10.64 -219.52   7.4
#3  -2.5981  1.7053 -2.6646 12.04 -1.7028  5.2132 -2.4566 10.64 -208.79   7.4
#4  -2.4905  1.7053 -2.5614 12.04 -1.6097  5.1979 -2.3560 10.64 -198.07   7.4
#5  -2.3830  1.7053 -2.4583 12.04 -1.5166  5.2012 -2.2555 10.64 -187.35   7.4
#...
#...
```

Comment: Minor comment: you removed `x1` instead of `y` from `df`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016484/5314416) but pivoted longer so data could be plotted more easily with facetting:

```r
library(randomForest)
#> randomForest 4.7-1.1
#> Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.
library(tidyverse)
library(pdp)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pdp'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     partial
x1 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x2 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x3 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x4 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
x5 <- rnorm(100,0,1)
y <- x1*100 + x2*10
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y)

rf <- randomForest(y~., data=df)

var <- names(df |> select(-y))

map(var, ~partial(rf, pred.var = .x)) |>  
  map_df(pivot_longer, cols = 1) |> 
  ggplot(aes(value, yhat)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>